# Predictive typing functionality in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, usability

Predictive typing is a handy feature on many mobile phones.

How would/can you implement predictive typing in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Predictive Typing is really a separate concern from the display of the predicted string.

You'd implement the predictive typing algorithm, then just use WPF to display the options.  In terms of display, there are many alternatives, including using Popup, a separate TextBlock, a custom control (to show the "predicted" text after the current entry point, etc.  This could mainly be a control that just takes a standard TextBox and templates it with the prediction over the top/after/etc.

Be aware, though, that [T9 is a patented algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9_(predictive_text)), licensed by most phone vendors - so you may run into patent issues implementing your own versions....

Comment: Are there no open source/non-patented alternatives?

Comment: @jasonk: As far as I know, the patent is actually on the technique of suggesting text on mobile devices.  Consult a patent lawyer for full details, though, if you really need to know...